# Doctrine Query: Select from associations

Tags: filter, doctrine, associations, dql

i am trying to create the a query for the following situation, but first the used entities:

User:

```
/**
 * Friendships to me (the user)
 *
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Friendship", mappedBy="to", fetch="EAGER")
 */
protected $friendshipsTo;

/**
 * Friendships from me (the user)
 *
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Friendship", mappedBy="from", fetch="EAGER")
 */
protected $friendshipsFrom;
```

Friendship:

```
/**
 * The user who started the friend request
 * 
 * @var \Entity\User
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="friendshipsFrom")
 */
protected $from = null;

/**
 * The user who got the friend request
 * 
 * @var \Entity\User
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="friendshipsTo")
 */
protected $to = null;
```

I hope this pretty much explains it. If I add a friend, a new friendship entity will be created with me as "from" and the other user as "to".

So now I want to select all friends of a user. I already figured that out, here's my solution:

```
$query = $qb->select('u, ff, ft')
            ->from('KontakteApp\Api\Entity\User', 'u')
            ->leftJoin('u.friendshipsTo', 'ft')
            ->leftJoin('u.friendshipsFrom', 'ff')
            ->where('ft.from = :user')
            ->orWhere('ff.to = :user')
            ->andWhere('u.id != :user')
            ->getQuery();
```

So what's the problem now? I realized that in this case if I find a friend (here id = 3) of the user with the id 2 with

```
 {
    "id": 3,
    "friendshipFrom": [
        {
            "id": 42,
            "from": 3,
            "to": 2,
            "status": "open"
        },
       **HERE ARE NO MORE FRIENDSHIPS**
    ],
    "friendshipTo": [
        This is array is full of friendships of this user
    ]
}
```

there are no more friendships in friendshipsFrom except the one which had the user show up in my select. This happens because of select('u, **ff**, ft'). 
Now I would like the same happen to friendshipsTo, so in this case friendshipsTo of the friend should be empty.

To sum up: How do I filter associated entities?